# composer require local git package without dev-master

Tags: php, composer-php, package, local

I want to create a package that will be stored on **local** machine in git repository.

I don't want to require package this way:

```
composer require vendor/package:dev-master
```

but simply

```
composer require vendor/package
```

Using external services like github, packagist, bitbucket is not an option in this case.

Do you know how to create such a package?

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I would say is Composer is meant to manage dependencies for whatever machine you are on.  That means, if I want to set up your project on my machine, composer will take care of fetching all dependencies.  If the code is only found on your machine, I won't be able to set up your project on my computer.

My 3 suggestions would be:

1. Put the dependent package within your project and commit it.  If it can't have its own repo, but your current project is dependent on it, then I would commit it in your project.  That way, all dependencies will be there.  If you can't commit it for privacy, you could use a private repository.  If that isn't an option either, then you'll have to go on to my second suggestion.
2. If you can't commit it to any repo, but you can host it online, then you can host the code in a zip file at some public url.  Then you can tell composer where to find the code.  Look at the part about inlining packages in the repositories section of your composer.json [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories).
3. If you can't commit it and you can't host it online, then you have to tell composer where it will be found on the server.  You can do that with the [psr-4](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) or the [psr-0](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0) fields in the composer.json file.  For example:

`{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "packageName\\": "/path/to/package/"
        }
    }
}`

Doing it this way will require anyone that wants to set up your project on another computer will have to download the dependent package on their own, and put it in the appropriate path on their machine.